# How to devide N equal parts by value (excel)

Tags: python, sql, excel, database, rows

I want to  devide N equal parts by value in excel. But i cann't.

One part of data:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EuRWr.png)

In the example above, Total count equal = 2,765 but i want to devide 3 equal parts by value. One part total count equal around 900

Comment: 2765 / 3 is not an integer result, there is a remainder from the division. You can easily check by adding the numbers: 2+7+6+5 = 20 so not divisible by 3.

Answer (score 1):

To get an integer result use roundup():

```
=roundup(2765/3,0)
```

But that might affect your calculations down the line, you need to decide what you want to do.

2765 / 3 is not an integer result, there is a remainder from the division. You can easily check by adding the numbers: 2+7+6+5 = 20 so not divisible by 3.

Comment: Sir very well explained.!